# Having trouble with creating tables using foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am trying creating two tables, aluno = student and  usuario = user. MySQL Workbench keep showing me that codigo in table usario doesn´t exist. Anyone can help me plz?

```
drop database `web2`;

CREATE DATABASE `web2` DEFAULT CHARSET latin1;

USE `web2`;

CREATE TABLE `aluno` (
   `id_aluno` bigint(20) not null auto_increment,
   `nome` varchar(100) not null,
   `cpf` varchar(20) not null,
   `rg` varchar(20) not null,
   `dataDeNascimento` date not null,
   `endereco` varchar(50),   
   `cidade` varchar(150),   
   `telefoneFixo` varchar(14),
   `telefoneCelular` varchar(14),
   `email` varchar(30) not null,   
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_aluno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `aluno` (`id_aluno`, `nome`, `cpf`, `rg`,`dataDeNascimento`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `telefoneFixo`,
 `telefoneCelular`,`email`) VALUES ('1', 'Marcela', '255665696363', '2153263699',
 '1985-07-08', 'Rua Hum', 'Belo Horizonte', '(35)54321-9876', '(35)54321-9876','marcela@bh.mg');

INSERT INTO `aluno` (`id_aluno`, `nome`, `cpf`, `rg`,`dataDeNascimento`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `telefoneFixo`,
 `telefoneCelular`,`email`) VALUES ('2', 'Paulo', '275865696361', '2183255599','1983-02-05', 'Rua Dois', 'Bela Vista', '(11)12345-6789',
 '(11)12345-6789', 'paulo@saopaulo.sp');

 INSERT INTO `aluno` (`id_aluno`, `nome`, `cpf`, `rg`,`dataDeNascimento`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `telefoneFixo`,
 `telefoneCelular`,`email`) VALUES ('3', 'Marcos', '275812656361', '2183255599','1983-02-12', 'Rua Dois', 'Bela Vista', '(11)12345-6790',
 '(11)12345-6789', 'paulo@saopaulo.sp');

INSERT INTO `aluno` (`id_aluno`, `nome`, `cpf`, `rg`,`dataDeNascimento`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `telefoneFixo`,
 `telefoneCelular`,`email`) VALUES ('4', 'Rodolfo', '569865696361', '2183255599','1983-05-28', 'Rua Dois', 'Bela Vista', '(11)12345-6791',
 '(11)12345-6789', 'paulo@saopaulo.sp');

INSERT INTO `aluno` (`id_aluno`, `nome`, `cpf`, `rg`,`dataDeNascimento`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `telefoneFixo`,
 `telefoneCelular`,`email`) VALUES ('5', 'Larissa', '275865696361', '2183255599','1983-02-01', 'Rua Dois', 'Bela Vista', '(11)12345-6792',
 '(11)12345-6789', 'paulo@saopaulo.sp');


CREATE TABLE `usuario` (
   `id` bigint(20) not null auto_increment,   
   `login` varchar(10) not null,
   `senha` varchar(10) not null,   
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`codigo`) REFERENCES aluno (`id_aluno`),
   UNIQUE KEY (`login`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `usuario` (`id`, `login`, `senha`, `codigo` ) VALUES ('1', 'marcela', '54321', '1');

INSERT INTO `usuario` (`id`, `login`, `senha`, `codigo` ) VALUES ('2', 'paulo', '12345', '2');

INSERT INTO `usuario` (`id`, `login`, `senha`, `codigo` ) VALUES ('3', 'gustavo', '52321', '3');

INSERT INTO `usuario` (`id`, `login`, `senha`, `codigo` ) VALUES ('4', 'leandro', '19315', '4');

INSERT INTO `usuario` (`id`, `login`, `senha`, `codigo` ) VALUES ('5', 'bruna', '14045', '5');
```

Comment: You haven't added that column to your `usario` table though. You only created columns `id`, `login`, and `senha`. Create `codigo` column just the same as those three so that the `FOREIGN KEY` definition can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the "codigo" column name in "CREATE TABLE `usuario`"

```
...
`codigo`    bigint(20)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `codigo` defined in create table statement:

```
 CREATE TABLE `usuario` (
   `id` bigint(20) not null auto_increment,   
   `login` varchar(10) not null,
   `senha` varchar(10) not null,
   `codigo` bigint(20)
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`codigo`) REFERENCES aluno (`id_aluno`),
   UNIQUE KEY (`login`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

The reason for this is that foreign keys are constraints *applied* to columns, so the table first needs the column to which the foreign key constraint is applied.